# RMI cannot find bound object?

Tags: java, rmi, remote-access

I have the folloving RMI server:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    try{
        ChatSystemImpl chatSystem = new ChatSystemImpl();
        ChatSystem chatSystem_stub = (ChatSystem) UnicastRemoteObject.exportObject(chatSystem, 6001);

        Registry registry = LocateRegistry.getRegistry("localhost", 6001);
        registry.bind("ChatSystem1", chatSystem_stub);

        System.out.println("Server up.");
    }
    catch(Exception ex){
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

When I run it I get:

```
ava.rmi.NoSuchObjectException: no such object in table
    at sun.rmi.transport.StreamRemoteCall.exceptionReceivedFromServer(StreamRemoteCall.java:273)
    at sun.rmi.transport.StreamRemoteCall.executeCall(StreamRemoteCall.java:251)
    at sun.rmi.server.UnicastRef.invoke(UnicastRef.java:377)
    at sun.rmi.registry.RegistryImpl_Stub.bind(Unknown Source)
    at fr.inp.ensimag.examples.chatsystem.Main.main(Main.java:30)
```

Well I have no idea whats wrong... Staring on it for more then 2 hours right now.

This is the interface (if needed):

```
public interface ChatSystem extends Remote{
    void registerUser(UserInfo newUser) throws RemoteException;
    void unregisterUser(UserInfo user) throws RemoteException;
    boolean userExists(UserInfo user) throws RemoteException;
    void send(MessageInfo message) throws RemoteException;
}
```

The implementation has following header, the body just contains methods that are not really implemented, they just thow `UnsupportedOperationException` :

```
public class ChatSystemImpl implements ChatSystem
```

The `ChatSystem` interface is in other project then the rest of source code if it is of any importance.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Your Registry has been unexported. This usually means that you are running it in a JVM via LocateRegistry.createRegistry() and you have let it become garbage-collected. The result of that method should be stored in a static variable. It may also mean that you never started the Registry in the first place.